Wexpect ssh authorization script
I have this code and it is not outputing anything and is not running the script
import wexpect
import sys



child = wexpect.spawn("ssh user@ip")
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect("user@ip's password:")
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.sendline('user_password')
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect('$')
child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.sendline('sudo su')
child.logfile = sys.stdout


I have tried everything, red the docs, but it is still not working

What is it that you are trying to do? I see wexpect with expect() actions, but no response to those actions with something like sendline, which is confusing.
